# CMake's find_package does not find library added with add_subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I'm building a test project to learn libraries `zeromq` with `cppmq`, and I want to include both libraries as subdirectories. I currently have the following structure:

```
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- deps
|   |-- cppzmq-4.3.0
|   |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |   `-- rest of files
|   |-- zeromq-4.3.1
|   |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |   `-- rest of files
`-- main.cpp
```

I've tried with the following `CMakeLists`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(PruebaZeroMQ)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_subdirectory(deps/zeromq-4.3.1)
add_subdirectory(deps/cppzmq-4.3.0)

add_executable(PruebaZeroMQ main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(PruebaZeroMQ
        libzmq
        cppzmq)
```

When I run cmake, I get the following error:

```
-- Detected CPPZMQ Version - 4.3.0
-- CMake libzmq package not found, trying again with pkg-config (normal install of zeromq)
CMake Error at deps/cppzmq-4.3.0/CMakeLists.txt:20 (message):
  ZeroMQ was not found, neither as a CMake package nor via pkg-config
```

`cppmq` depends on `zeromq`, and looks like it tries to load it using `find_package`, so I tried to modify `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` so it could find the `ZeroMQConfig.cmake` file, but it fails too, with the same error:

```
add_subdirectory(deps/zeromq-4.3.1)
list (APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/deps/zeromq-4.3.1 ")

add_subdirectory(deps/cppzmq-4.3.0)
```

Is there a way of achieving this? I'd rather not install the libraries system-wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to manually `find_package`, CMake showed the following error message:

```
  Add the installation prefix of "ZeroMQ" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ZeroMQ_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
```

So I tried that, using:

```
set(ZeroMQ_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/deps/zeromq-4.3.1)
```

And it worked.